# How to change text in a button when using onclick, to stay permanent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Im working on a function in wordpress that I wanna be able to click on a button, and when a button is clicked, the text inside the button changes and redirects the user to another page (I want to change the text inside the button from Create to Edit).
If I refresh the page or go back to the page, the text inside the button is not displaying the changed text. I want the text inside the button to always stay changed.

```
<a class="cc-btn">
    <input id="texts" onclick="changeStyle()" value="Create"></input>
</a>

<script>
    function changeStyle() {
        document.getElementById("texts").value="newButtonValue";
        window.location.replace("/xxxx/?page_id=xx");
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just do it in PHP if you're using WP?

Comment: changes with js is not permanent for this you have to have a serverside lang.

Comment: @dcclassics Hi! Can you do it in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like that the changes will still remain once you refresh the page, you cannot do it using JavaScript only.

you will have to use the server side and save the new text and put it into the button value once the page is rendered. (or of course it`s possible to do something ugly like saving the data in a cookie and then use JavaScript only - but this is wrong )

Comment: Ok, I understand. Do you know some examples out there?

Comment: I'm not a master with PHP but you should write something like : '<input id="texts" onclick="changeStyle()" value="'. $value. '"></input>' in your php page and the $value should be calculated base on some data you saved...

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i got your issue, but you could try it:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    if(window.location.pathname == '/xxxx/?page_id=xx') {
       $('#texts').val('Edit');
    }
});
```